# I have an array of different IDs and I want to fetch data from each IDs . Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of mongoDB ids.

```
const pId =  ['62b3968ad7cc2315f39450f3', '62b37f9b99b66e7287de2d44']
```

I used forEach to seperate the IDs like :

```
pId.forEach((item)=>{
console.log(item)
})
```

but I have a database(products) from where I want to fetch data from. So I tried

```
   const [product, setProduct] = useState([{}]);
useEffect(() => {
            pId?.forEach((item) => {
                const getProduct = async () => {
                    try {
                        const res = await userRequest.get("/products/find/" + item)
                        setProduct(res.data)
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                }
                getProduct()
            })
        }, [pId])
```

I used `useState[{}]` because I want to collect the data in an array of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I used useState[{}] because I want to collect the data in an array of objects.

Your code isn't collecting objects into an array. It's setting each result of the query as the single state item (overwriting previous ones).

If you want to get all of them as an array, build an array; one way to do that is `map` with the `map` callback providing a promise of each element, then use `Promise.all` to wait for all of those promises to settle:

```
// The usual advice is to use plurals for arrays, not singulars ("products", not "product")
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]); // Start with an empty array
useEffect(() => {
    if (pId) {
        Promise.all(pId.map((item) => userRequest.get("/products/find/" + item)))
            .then((products) => setProducts(products))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
}, [pId]);
```

Note that if `pId` changes while one or more `userRequest.get` calls are still outstanding, you'll get into a race condition. If `userRequest.get` provides a way to cancel in-flight calls (like `fetch` does), you'll want to use that to cancel the in-flight calls using a cleanup callback in the `useEffect`. For example, **if** `userRequest.get` accepted an `AbortSignal` instance (like the built-in `fetch` does), it would look like this:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const { signal } = controller;
    if (pId) {
        Promise.all(pId.map((item) => userRequest.get("/products/find/" + item, { signal })))
            .then((products) => setProducts(products))
            .catch((error) => {
                if (!signal.aborted) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
    }
    return () => {
        controller.abort();
    };
}, [pId]);
```

Again, that's conceptual; `userRequest.get` may not accept an `AbortSignal`, or may accept it differently; the goal there is to show how to cancel a previous request using a `useEffect` cleanup callback.

Comment: We've written the same answer at the same time, only yours is much more explanatory :) 
+1

Answer (score 1):

You can map through the ids and create a promise for each, then use `Promise.all()` and at last set the products state:

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from 'react'

const Example = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const ids = ['62b3968ad7cc2315f39450f3', '62b37f9b99b66e7287de2d44']

  useEffect(() => {
    if(ids) Promise.all(ids.map(id => userRequest.get("/products/find/" + id).then(r => r.data))).then(results => setProducts(results))
  }, [ids])
}
```

I renamed some of the variables for clarity to the future visitors. (`pId` to `ids` and `product` to `products`).

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your `product` array with an individual result from each request. A simple solution would be to append to the array instead:

```
setProduct(product => [...product, res.data]); // take the old array and append the new item
```

As T.J. Crowder rightly suggested in the comments, you would keep appending to the initial `product` state when using the simple setter, so you need to use callback form which receives the current state as a parameter and returns the update.

I suggest you rename that particular state to `products`/`setProducts` to make clear it's an array.

Not directly related to the question, but bear in mind that firing a huge number of individual requests may cause performance degradation on the client and backend; there are plenty of options to deal with that, so I am not going into more detail here.

Comment: That won't work in the OP's `forEach`; the `product` it closes over won't have previous entries in it when subsequent ones are done, so only the **last** result from `userRequest.get` will be added to the array. When building state based on existing state, you'd have to use the callback form of the state setter.

Comment: Good point, I'll amend my response.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's possible. just change your code a bit:

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState([]); // empty array is enough for initialzing

useEffect(() => {

 async function doSomethingAsync() {
            
            if(!pId) return;
            let newArray = [];
            for(let item of pId) {

              try {
                        const res = await userRequest.get("/products/find/" + item)
                        newArray.push(res.data);  // push data to temporary array
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
            }

            // set new state once
            setProduct(newArray);

 }
doSomethingAsync();

}, [pId])
```